# Can we pull REXX SQL output values into ISPF panel?

Tags: rexx, ispf

I Have created a REXX program to fetch 3 columns from a table.

I have kept  temporary variables to hold SQL values (takes automatic datatype as per input)
Its like:

```
 ADDRESS DSNREXX "EXECSQL FETCH C1 INTO :IN, :CR, :TN"
```

Now i have created A Panel, but i only know that we assign options.
Which is done like giving

```
 %option_name
```

But havent got any book or online forum about how to display those REXX program variables to screen.

There are forums only for Calling a panel which have its own functionality.

Comment: Are you trying to display on Ispf panels ???, I do not understand the relevance of %option_name. Mind you it has been a while since I used ISPF.

Answer (score 3):

In ISPF panels, any 8 character rexx variable can be displayed either using the **&var.** format or prefixing it with a field definition char (say _ for an entry field). e.g.

Rexx:

```
 v1 = '...'
 v2 = '..'
 v3 = '.'
```

ISPF Panel:

```
)body
+  V1 = &v1.        Display the value (... will be displayed)  
+  v2 :_V2     +    Allow the user to update v2
```

See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zvm.v54.dmsa3/ispfpan.htm

Sample ispf panel definition

```
)BODY
%---------------------------  EMPLOYEE RECORDS  ------------------------------
%COMMAND ===>_ZCMD
%
%EMPLOYEE SERIAL: &EMPSER
+
+   TYPE OF CHANGE%===>_TYPECHG  +  (NEW, UPDATE, OR DELETE)
+
+   EMPLOYEE NAME:
+     LAST   %===>_LNAME          +
+     FIRST  %===>_FNAME          +
+     INITIAL%===>_I+
+
+   HOME ADDRESS:
+     LINE 1 %===>_ADDR1                                    +
+     LINE 2 %===>_ADDR2                                    +
+     LINE 3 %===>_ADDR3                                    +
```

---

If more than 1 row is being displayed, you may find it useful to

- Add the returned rows to a **ISPF table**
- Display the table using the [TBDISPL](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00%2Fch6tbd.htm) service.
- **Note:** for Table display panels you must include a )Model section for data in the table

If you want to use ISPF Tables see http://rexxpertise.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/ispf-tables-defining-and-building.html for examples of [TBCREATE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00%2Ftcreat.htm) and [TBADD](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00%2Fispsg477.htm)

Also for a [complicated example ISPF Table](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21024010)

---

Have a look at [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386979/how-do-i-display-a-table-to-an-ispf-panel-with-rexx-then-retrieve-back-updated-u)

General ISPF info is available at:

- [OS/390 V2R5.0-V2R7.0 ISPF Examples](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/ISPEXA02/CCONTENTS?DT=19981119125546)
- [OS/390 V2R10.0 ISPF Dialog Developer's Guide and Reference](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/ISPDGD04/CCONTENTS?DT=20000717151307)
- [OS/390 V2R10.0 ISPF Services Guide](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/ISPSER04/CCONTENTS?DT=20000712152926)

Comment: Documentation for supported versions of z/OS (OS/390 went out of service in 2004) are available at http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/library/bkserv/index.html or the IBM Knowledge Center at https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/.